# Why does pg_hba.conf sometimes have random rules added to it? (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql

I have postgres 10.4 set up on a Linux machine, and sometimes there will randomly be rules at the top of pg_hba.conf that only allows an MD5 connection by a user "pgdbadm". I'm not sure if the database got hacked but after changing the password and checking that a pgdbadm doesn't exist, I still see the new rules from time to time. Is it possible that the database is compromised?

The three rules, if I recall correctly are as follows:

```
local all all 0.0.0.0/0 reject
host all postgres 0.0.0.0/0 reject
host all pgdbadm 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

Any explanation as to what is going on would be appreciated, as well as potential solutions.

**EDIT**: I have discovered that when setting up pg_hba.conf I used a rule where all connections didn't require a password. This probably allowed a bot to log in and create unwanted databases/other things, so I will do a clean install of Ubuntu and backup the databases.

Comment: I’d back the database up & reinstall the OS from scratch. If the machine has been compromised there could be a root kit (or similar)

Comment: I described how I replicated the hack with no shell access - remotely through pgAdmin 4 here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52197486/fatal-pg-hba-conf-rejects-connection-for-host-127-0-0-1-user-postgres-dat/52778024#52778024

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you seem to have surmised, "pgdbadm" is an account created by hackers. It is the known account created a recent crypto-mining attacker who exploits unsecured postgresql superuser accounts.  Changing the pg_hba.conf is also part of his MO.

Comment: Just encountered this issue recently. I believe it can only happen if the hacker has access to my EC2 host, which means my SSH key is compromised?

Comment: @c2 If they have access to a PostgreSQL superuser account, they can use that to get access to the files of the EC2 host account which is running the PostgreSQL server.  They don't need to have compromised your ssh key to do this.  Of course if you left your private key lying around, they could have nabbed it.  But usually an EC2 host will only have the public key, not the private one.

Answer (score 2):

In a standard Postgres installation, no rules are added to pg_hba.conf by any program whatsoever. All editing of this file is done manually.

You either have some person doing this or someone has added a program - either with benevolent or malicious intent - to do this for them.

You should solve this

1. in your organisation by determining who is doing this; and
2. by changing passwords and removing/revoking any SSH keys

Comment: I was going to ask, before anything, what the pgdbadm user is...there's nothing on google about it

Comment: @ethanc: pgdbadm  is not a "standard" Postgres (or Linux if I'm not mistaken) user. Someone in your organization must have added that user

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name As I'm writing this I'm backing up my databases, but yeah, I'm the only one who uses the server so it must have been a bot.

Comment: I just came across the same symptoms, with the same pgdbadm user etc.. not sure if it's simply a matter of bots

Comment: Do either of you have any Postgres admin tools of any sort installed?