# Postgres 9.6.10 pg_hba.conf altered

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

We have an Ubuntu dedicated server. A couple of weeks ago we started to notice that when the postgresql service restarts, the directory `/var/lib/postgresql` turns readonly.

We changed the permissions manually, but recently we found that the file `pg_hba.conf` has extra lines:

```
host all postgres 0.0.0.0/0 reject
host all pgdbadm 0.0.0.0/0 md5
host all odoo 0.0.0.0/0 reject
```

Is it possible we have some kind of malware?

Is there a solution without having to format the server?

Comment: See [Why does pg_hba.conf sometimes have random rules added to it?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/215294/why-does-pg-hba-conf-sometimes-have-random-rules-added-to-it-postgresql)

Comment: "when the postgresql service restarts, the directory /var/lib/postgresql turns readonly."  If this is reliable, it should be possible to trace through the start-up scripts to figure out what is doing it.  PostgreSQL cannot start with its data in a read only directory and pg_hba.conf can't matter until it is started, so it seems odd for malware to intentionally do both of these things together.